How to use meson as a cuda build system
Suppose I have a hello.cu source file:
#include <iostream>

int
main(int, char**) {
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

With the following meson.build it should have been possible to compile it.
project('hello', 'cuda')
executable('hello', 'hello.cu')

However, during the meson setup phase I receive:
meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Compiler nvcc cannot compile programs.

On the other hand, it works if I compile it manually as:
nvcc -o hello -ccbin /usr/bin/g++-13 hello.cu

I tried setting the CXX straight to /usr/bin/g++-13, as CUDA 12 does not support gcc 14.1.
However CXX=/usr/bin/g++-13 meson setup build led to the same error.

Can you post your PATH. I ran what you have posted and it builds for me with no issues. I can show you my steps if you wish. I am running an RHEL 8 container wwith gcc 8.5.0 and cuda 12.

I'd imagine that meson is producing a more complete error message somewhere, maybe in a log file, that shows why nvcc is failing

@AlanBirtles yes, it provides a log under build/meson-logs with a longer error description. Thanks, that helped me find the issue.

Meson performs sanity checks during the setup phase. If it fails, as caused by nvcc and g++ mismatch, it alerts the user that nvcc cannot compile programs.
However, since meson 0.57.1, one can pass the flag -Dcuda_ccbindir=PATH_TO_GCC to specify the desired gcc and g++, even during sanity checks.
